# In the decomposition of a symmetric matrix $A = \sum_{i=0}^{n} \lambda_i u_i u_i^\top$, what is the term $u_i u_i^\top$?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, matrix-decomposition

I'm not sure what $u_i u_i^\top$ is. It looks like two vectors being multiplied, but that would produce a scalar (doesn't make sense that the sum of scalars is a matrix...). I don't know what to search for and so I can't even find the proof for this. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Dot product indeed produces a scalar

Comment: But how does that make sense? The sum of scalars is a matrix? @edm

Comment: $u_iu_i^\top$ is a matrix of order $n\times n$ if $u_i$ is a column vector having $n$ rows. This is related to [outer product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product).

Comment: Well, is $u_i$ a row vector or column vector?

Comment: I didn't know what the outer product of two vectors were... should have taken advanced linear algebra as an undergraduate...

Comment: This is just ordinary matrix multiplication. $u$ is $n\times1$ and $u^T$ is $1\times n$, so the matrix product $uu^T$ is $n\times n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If vector $u$ is an $n$-dimensional column vector, $u u^T$ is an $n \times n$ matrix, with $(i,j)$ entry $u_i u_j$.  Thus

$$ \pmatrix{u_1\cr u_2 \cr u_3} \pmatrix{u_1 & u_2 & u_3} = \pmatrix{u_1^2 & u_1 u_2 & u_1 u_3\cr u_2 u_1 & u_2^2 & u_2 u_3\cr u_3 u_1 & u_3 u_2 & u_3^2}$$

Comment: Thank you! I should have taken Math 412 at UBC :)